# How to get rid of weird white bar in the minibuffer Emacs

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I have this weird issue where whenever I type down `:w` or any other kind of command which can be used in vim's command mode (I am using evil-mode in emacs so that I can vim emulation) I always get this weird white cursor at the bottom of the minibuffer. Could  you please tell me a way to get rid of this because it is really bugging me.

[image]

I thought that it may be useful if I included my init.el. If it is needed this is it:

```
(defun ali/initial-setup ()
  "Basic Settings to make emacs usable"
  (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Consolas" :height 120)
  (setq scroll-margin 6)
  (setq visible-bell 1) 
  (global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") 'keyboard-escape-quit)
  (setq inhibit-startup-message t) 
  (tool-bar-mode -1)
  (menu-bar-mode -1)
  (scroll-bar-mode -1)
  (setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1)))
  (setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
  (setq mouse-wheel-follow-mouse 't)
  (setq scroll-step 3)
  (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

  "Setting up fringes and truncated lines"
  (global-visual-line-mode t)
  (setq truncate-lines t)
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(internal-border-width . 1))
  (setq-default left-fringe-width  6)

  "Making the line numbers wider"
  (add-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode-hook '(lambda() (setq display-line-numbers-width 3)))
  
  "Getting rid of autosave files and other stuff"
  (setq make-lockfiles nil
        make-backup-files nil)
  (auto-save-mode -1)

  "Making splits always be vertical by default"
  (setq split-height-threshold nil
          split-width-threshold 0)

  (setq-default tab-width 4)
  (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
  (setq-default c-basic-offset 4
                c-default-style "linux"))

(defun ali/brackets()
  "Automatically completing brackets and pairs"
  (show-paren-mode 1)
  (electric-pair-mode 1)
  (setq electric-pair-pairs
        '((?\" . ?\")
          (?\{ . ?\}))))

;; Setting up packages
(require 'package)

(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(require 'package)

(package-initialize)

(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

(defvar packages-we-need '(org modus-themes evil ido))
(dolist (package packages-we-need)
  (unless (package-installed-p 'package)
    (package-install 'package)))

(defun ali/ido()
  "Setting up ido mode"
  (require 'ido)
  (setq ido-create-new-buffer 'always)
  "Making ido-mode work in M-x"
  (global-set-key
      "\M-x"
      (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (call-interactively
          (intern
          (ido-completing-read
          "M-x "
          (all-completions "" obarray 'commandp))))))
  (ido-everywhere t)
  (ido-mode 1))

(require 'modus-themes)
(load-theme 'modus-vivendi t)

(defun ali/evil()
  (require 'evil)

  "Making cursor always be a box"
  (setq evil-insert-state-cursor 'box)

  (evil-make-overriding-map ali-keymap 'normal 'motion)
  (evil-mode 1))

(let ((ali-keymap (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-h") 'evil-window-left)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-l") 'evil-window-right)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "M-d") '(lambda() (interactive) (execute-kbd-macro (read-kbd-macro "C-x d RET"))))
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-p") 'ido-switch-buffer)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-f") 'ido-find-file)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "M-=") 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "M--") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-=") 'text-scale-increase)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C--") 'text-scale-decrease)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-/") 'comment-line)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-S-i") 'display-line-numbers-mode)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "M-v") 'evil-window-vsplit)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "M-h") 'evil-window-split)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-S-h") 'help)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "C-d") 'kill-buffer)
    (define-key ali-keymap (kbd "M-1") '(lambda() (interactive) (execute-kbd-macro (read-kbd-macro "M-x make-directory RET"))))
    (defvar ali-keymap ali-keymap
      "These are my keybindings"))


(define-minor-mode ali-keybindings-mode
  nil
  :global t
  :lighter " keys"
  :keymap ali-keymap)

(ali-keybindings-mode 1)

(ali/initial-setup)
(ali/evil)
(ali/brackets)
(ali/ido)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes
   '("27a1dd6378f3782a593cc83e108a35c2b93e5ecc3bd9057313e1d88462701fcd" "0feb7052df6cfc1733c1087d3876c26c66410e5f1337b039be44cb406b6187c6" "57e3f215bef8784157991c4957965aa31bac935aca011b29d7d8e113a652b693" "0f7fa4835d02a927d7d738a0d2d464c38be079913f9d4aba9c97f054e67b8db9" "ddff22007104a1317014e48ff3d4911a83771a4ccf57185ccebf7f91339dbfb8" default))
 '(package-selected-packages '(geiser-stklos modus-themes evil)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved removing where I wrote `(setq-default left-fringe-width 6)` and instead I added `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(left-fringe . 5))`